# C++ how do you delete 2 pointers located in two vectors at the same time?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have two vectors, and a pointer added in both vectors.  What I want to do is add the int * pointer to both vectors, then delete the pointer. I want the pointer to be removed in each vector.  Is this possible in C++ without iterating through the vector.

```
std::vector<int *> A;
std::vector<int *> B:
int * ptr = new int(5);
A.push_back(ptr); // Add ptr to list A.
B.push_back(ptr); // Add ptr to list B.
// right here is where I want to delete pointer and update the vectors.
// A and B vector size should be 0 after the delete.
delete ptr;
```

I know I can iterate through both vectors and remove the element manually, but that adds a lot of time in a huge list.  I'm assuming I can also do a check to see if A[i] == NULL?

Comment: You need to remove the pointer from the vector BEFORE deleting it (even in the case of a single vector).  One way to do this would be with vector's `find` and `erase`. It would be better to not use raw pointers with ownership semantics in the first place.

Comment: `std::vector` does not have a `find()` method, you would have to use `std::find()` instead.

Comment: ***I'm assuming I can also do a check to see if A[i] == NULL?*** It won't be NULL after you free the memory and also deleting won't magically change the value stored in either vector. The old pointer will still be there (pointing to memory you no longer own) unless you remove it.

Comment: What is the design rationale behind this?  Why do you need to store raw pointers in a `std::vector<>` and then delete them?  There are issues with this approach, including exception safety.  If you really must store a dynamically allocated object use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the pointer to be removed in each vector. Is this possible in C++ without iterating through the vector.

No, it is not.  However, you do not have to iterate manually, you can use STL algorithms instead, eg:

```
A.erase(std::remove(A.begin(), A.end(), ptr), A.end());
B.erase(std::remove(B.begin(), B.end(), ptr), B.end());
```

Or:

```
auto iter = std::find(A.begin(), A.end(), ptr);
if (iter != A.end()) A.erase(iter);

auto iter = std::find(B.begin(), B.end(), ptr);
if (iter != B.end()) B.erase(iter);
```

> I'm assuming I can also do a check to see if `A[i] == NULL`?

You assume incorrectly, since you are not storing any NULL pointers in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You're using raw pointers so the onus is entirely on you to make sure you clean up properly. You're storing them into vectors which means you can't assume consistency in iterators or pointers into that storage if there's any possibility that the vector has mutated between inspections.

Therefore an iterative search is your only option here.

If any of those rules can be altered:

Using a set instead of a vector would increase your insertion costs but decrease your checking-for-removal costs. If the two tasks are balanced, this probably isn't worth it.

Switching to a `shared_ptr` to hold the allocated object and `weak_ptr`s in the arrays would mean that you didn't have to tend to removal up front; traversing your lists would simply require checking that each `weak_ptr`s still has a subject.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Standard class that does this, `weak_ptr`.

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<int>> A;
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<int>> B:
auto ptr = std::make_shared(5);
A.push_back(ptr); // Add ptr to list A.
B.push_back(ptr); // Add ptr to list B.
// right here is where I want to delete pointer and update the vectors.
ptr = nullptr;
// A and B vector size are 1; both A[0] and B[0] are .expired()
```

`weak_ptr` and `shared_ptr` work together. You can convert from one to the other and back. The difference is that `shared_ptr` keeps the pointed-to object alive. `weak_ptr` can only check if the object is still alive, which implies that there is at least one `shared_ptr` to the same object.